# print os.system() en python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Estaba practicando un pequeño programa en `socket` que permite acceder a la `shell` de la máquina servidor. El caso esta en que los p`r`int que se tendrían que mandar al cliente (que son la respuesta de `os.system()`) son numéricos (por ejemplo del `clear` es 0.

¿Alguien conoce el porque o la solución?

El código del cliente:

```
import socket

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)
try:
    s.connect(("192.168.43.241" , 4004))
    print "conexion establecida"

while True:
    mensaje = raw_input(">>")
    s.send(mensaje)
    print s.recv(1024)
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit()
```

el código del servidor:

```
import socket

print "INICANDO SERVIDOR..."

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET , socket.SOCK_STREAM)

try:
    s.bind(("192.168.43.241" , 4004))
    s.listen(5)
    sockets , data = s.accept()
    print str("conexion establecida")   
    while True:
        mensaje = socket.recv(1024)
    try:
        comando = os.system(mensaje)
    except:
        socket.send("Comando invalido")
    socket.send(comando)
 except KeyboardInterrupt:
     exit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por que `os.system(mensaje)` retorna un "EXIT CODE", normalmente 0 si el comando funciono correctamente, lo que tu quieres en realidad es redirigir el output del comando al `socket.send`, una forma de hacerlo es así:

```
import subprocess

proc = subprocess.Popen(comando, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
socket.send(out)
```